# Throttle per-day index creation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is my problem.

We have an ES installation to which we send daily logs in Logstash pattern, that is, there is an index for each day.  The problem arises when we send a bunch of logs which are very sparse and cover a few years.  Elasticsearch 1.7.2 (Debian GNU/Linux, Java 8) tries to create indices for 500+ days and consistently crashes.  Sometimes it can be brought back, but it will not index anything without any explanation (no errors in logs), and most or all shards will be red and unassigned.

I figured that default settings allow for unlimited indices to be created in parallel.  Because indexing the very same logs day-by-day waiting for the previous index to settle down before attempting to index the next day works just fine.

Is there a way to throttle index creation in Elasticsearch (say, configure that no more than 1 or N parallel index creation tasks are executed at a time)?

Comment: Each open index and the related shards create overhead in elasticsearch, so you're probably having memory problems.  Assuming you don't want last year's logs, you can use the ruby{} filter to check their age and drop{} them.